# TypeError: f1_score() got an unexpected keyword argument 'average'

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, scikit-learn, measure

I'm extracting the F1_macro value using f1_score sklearn function.

I doing that for my Keras network, this is the code:

```
Y_dev_pred = self.model.predict([self.dev[0], self.dev[1]], batch_size=self.BatchSize, verbose=0)
Y_dev_pred = np.argmax(Y_dev_pred, axis=1)
self.Y_dev = np.argmax(self.dev[2], axis=1)
print('####### ', self.Y_dev.shape, ' ', Y_dev_pred.shape)
print(self.Y_dev, ' ### ', Y_dev_pred)
print(f1_score(self.Y_dev, Y_dev_pred, average='macro'))
```

Output:

> ```
> #######  (19647,)   (19647,)
> [1 0 0 ... 2 0 2]  ###  [0 0 0 ... 2 1 0]
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "main.py", line 185, in <module>
>     deep.run_model(reTrain=True)
>   File ".../models/DL.py", line 477, in run_model
>     self.evaluate_on_test()
>   File ".../models/DL.py", line 448, in evaluate_on_test
>     print(f1_score(self.Y_dev, Y_dev_pred, average='macro'))
> TypeError: f1_score() got an unexpected keyword argument 'average'
> ```

What is the problem, did I miss something?

Comment: That's weird, the docs have very similar calls as examples, and the signature indicates this should work. This is the latest version of scikit-learn right? Could it be that it is calling some other `f1_score` method?

Comment: The most likely reason is that your `sklearn`'s version is wrong.

Comment: You might also want to see if it's on their end. I found [this Github issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/4319) where the cause was a typo, which was fixed in a future PR.

Comment: @TheGamer007, Yes, I discover it now. I was calling another f1_score method .. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this error when in my code i had another function called f1_score as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check if any of your y_true labels or y_predicted labels has only two classes? check the unique values in each. average macro works only for multiclass if any of the variables has only two classes it throws a error like this!
and yes check version of your sklearn,

Answer (score 0):

My scikit learn is   `Name: scikit-learn   Version: 0.24.2`
I'm still getting this issue. My problem is multi-class not binary.
If i remove the average i got this error  `Target is multiclass but average='binary'. Please choose another average setting, one of [None, 'micro', 'macro', 'weighted'].`

Comment: because you have a multiclass problem but `average='binary'` is set as it's the default.